# Splitting up a string using regex

Tags: python, regex, morse-code

Im making a program to parse morse code. The input is in string format. Here is an example:

```
Input = '/.- .-.. .---- ..-. -.- - ..--- -.-. .... .....'

Desired Output = ['/', '.-', '.-..', '.----', '..-.', '-.-', '-', '..---', '-.-.', '....', '.....']
```

The `/` represents a space in the text. I would like to split the forward slash off to its own element and not get rid of it. The spaces however I do want to get rid of. Doing an expression like `re.split(' |/')` gets rid of the forward slash. How should I go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could be tricky because the `re` module does not support string splits on lookahead patterns with zero width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linguistically non-sophisticated approach using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and a custom key function that distinguishes `'/'`, `' '` and rest:

```
from itertools import groupby

s = '/.- .-.. .---- ..-. -.- - ..--- -.-. .... .....'
key = lambda c: c if c in ' /' else 'x'
[''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(s, key=key) if k != ' ']
# ['/', '.-', '.-..', '.----', '..-.', '-.-', '-', '..---', '-.-.', '....', '.....']
```